# Upgrade azure VM basic SKU to standard using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I am performing the same task, upgrading the azure VM public ip SKU
from basic to standard but using terraform code. My plan is

1. Disassociate nic from UI
2. Include SKU = "Standard" in my existing terraform VM code (IP allocation is static and is not specified to any zones)

I executed terraform plan but didn't find this particular change.

I am a complete beginner in terraform. Can anyone suggest whether this will work? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The SKU needs to be on your Public IP resource, not your VM.